# Enhance attribute in Ractive is set to false by default - is there a reason for this?

Tags: ractivejs

I've been working on a mini project in Ractive, which uses the enhance: attribute.

My question is about the default value for the "enhance" attribute - I notice out of curiosity that this is set to false by default. I would have thought that it would be more sensible to reuse elements where possible in the DOM, surely? I'm sure there is a reason for this, but it's not clear from the docs - is anyone able to explain the rationale behind this please?

Comment: It's an opt-in feature for backwards-compatibility. Not all workflows and use-cases use DOM recycling, not all apps use server-side rendering. The feature might also construct the DOM differently (in unforseen ways) compared to older versions which could break an existing app.

Comment: Thanks - this makes perfect sense ;-)